# Dragging a window is laggy (windows do not follow the mouse while moving smoothly)

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, window-management

When trying to drag a window the whole screen becomes laggy and some windows when dragged do not even appear until I release the mouse. They do appear where the window was suppose to end up after the drag but the dragging animation that happens while dragging is not seen.

I am using a NVIDIA 9500 GT 1GB with the proprietary drivers, an Intel Core 2 Duo 8500 and 4GB RAM just to make sure that this is not the problem. In 11.04 it worked correctly when dragging.

Comment: Experiencing this too with similar hardware.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I've experienced something similar today, but never before. I am using a Radeon HD5850, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install *CompizConfig Settings Manager*:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And in *Composite*, disable *Detect Refresh Rate* and slide the *Refresh Rate* up to more than *70*.

Under *Mouse Polling Position*, change *Mouse Poll Interval* to *1*.

Disabling Plugin *Grid* also might help, **but that disables window snapping!!**

.

Comment: Before accepting the answer (Which it worked for almost all windows), the last windows that move laggy are the ones used by Wine. Any thoughts about this ones.

Comment: Notepad seems to work fine on my computer...

Comment: I tried a game. Am starting to think that the combination of Compiz activated for Unity + Wine running an OpenGL game makes the screen loose several FPS quickly.

Comment: In General Options, Enable Unredirect Fullscreen Windows. In Workarounds, enable Legacy Fullscreen Support, this will make fullscreen windows in wine run faster.

Comment: For me this doesn't work. GTX 560 Ti on 11.10.

Comment: Does this apply to Linux Mint Cinnamon (gtk3)?

Comment: No. This only works if you are using Compiz as the window manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem .. but the proposed fix didn't work.

What worked was to change the driver. I just typed "Additional Drivers" in dash. In the Additional Drivers window there was two proprietary drivers listed for my Nvidia card.

One was marked as "version current" and the other was marked as "post-release updates".

I changed it from "version current" to "post-release updates" and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by installing the newer NVIDIA drivers 295+ from alternative repository.

I should, mention the the above tricks did not worked for me.