# compiz settings manager problem

Tags: compiz

I installed the compiz settings manager, to try out some effects. But after installation i felt something unuseful and dragging the system speed.So, thought of removing the app. using terminal. And this is what happened the terminal and other applications take large amount of time to get opened,maximized, minimized,closed. Removed the settings manager, still the problem exists.

Comment: also wen i tried to end compiz using system manager, everything on my monitor fades away.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a very strange behaviour for compiz to say the least (standard values are not supposed to break your system, custom values are...), so I doubt that your problems are related to compiz (alone).

But assuming that ccsm is indeed the culprit, I'd suggest to simply reinstall it, reset it to standard settings, log out and in again.
If that didn't help, you can always **purge** the application, meaning that not only the application itself but all its settings as well are deleted.

Finally, still on the supposition that your problem relates to ccsm and that nothing of the above helped in any way, you can simply try to configure ccsm to function properly, like e.g. described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71750/dragging-a-window-is-laggy-windows-do-not-follow-the-mouse-while-moving-smoothl).

Good luck to you and best regards!

Comment: Great, congratulations! But for others with the same problem: which of the above worked for you exactly?

Comment: Corleone, don't hesitate to upvote FuzzyQ's answer and/or mark it as accepted, since it is very useful for feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the System Monitor app from the Dash Menu. In the Processes tab, you can see if there is any program that is using all the memory of your computer.

Comment: no did not help, bro!! got any other suggestion? @agmenor