# Ubuntu is slow, mouse lags and windows drag and blink slowly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, mouse

I have had a rough time installing Ubuntu in my laptop. After changing settings in the BIOS and setting nomodoset, I finally made it. The problem now is that everything is very slow: windows opening and dragging is very slow, the mouse freezes for few moments and then continues normally, etc etc. The problems I am having occur both with Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04. This problem resembles a bit when I was running heavy processes that used swap memory in my old laptop\ubuntu.

My problem is similar to this one: [nvidia's driver loop and Intel's slow in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873864/nvidias-driver-loop-and-intels-slow-in-ubuntu-16-04)

**My laptop:** ASUS N552VX-76A95SB1, 16Gb RAM, Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M,Intel Core i7 6700HQ

**Settings changed in Bios**: Disabled Fast Boot, Secure Boot, Enabled Launch CSM & PXE OpROM policy.

**Other changes** **I tried:**

- Using several proprietary drivers for the graphic card (378,381,375,384), including the latest (384.69).
- setting vm.swappiness=0
- Used Compiz: [Dragging a window is laggy (windows do not follow the mouse while moving smoothly)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71750/dragging-a-window-is-laggy-windows-do-not-follow-the-mouse-while-moving-smoothl)
- System monitor shows very little activity, no swap mem being used, less than 1Gb RAM being used. No heavy processes running.

I don't know if the processing speed is slow or not, what I am sure is that the "look and feel" is very very slow.

I have no more ideas, so I kindly ask for your help.

Comment: Something is wrong: there were 2 answers here yesterday that are gone and I added something to the post that is also not here.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out: This is a problem that only occurs with the 64-bit version. I switch to Ubuntu 17.04 32-bit and it works fine.